# Python error check bug?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pool

I have the following script:

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, Pool

def worker():
    r = other.work()
    return r

def main():
    pool = Pool(4)
    result = pool.apply_sync(worker,())
    result.wait()
```

In **worker()**, I call function **work()** from another module '**other**', However, I forget to import the module '**other**'. But when I ran this python script, python didn't report any Exception. Is this a bug ?

Comment: Your code snippet contains an error on line 9 with that comma inside the empty-set: result = pool.apply_sync(worker,(,))

Comment: Its possible that the async call is supressing the output of an exception.  To test this you could write a function that raises an exception and see what happens. The other possibility is that there is some class other already within the namespace that python calls instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any errors that are raised in the spawned processes will remain silent until you actually retrieve the result.

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, Pool

def worker():
    r = other.work()
    return r

def main():
    pool = Pool(4)

    # note: this is apply_async, not apply_sync
    result = pool.apply_async(worker,())
    result.wait()

    # See here
    actual_result = result.get()
```

This will raise:

```
NameError: global name 'other' is not defined
```

What you have named `result` is a `multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult` object which is more like the promise of a return value, than a return value itself.